# Downward pointing triangle with text right side up

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

In a diagram, I have a triangle shape containing text. It points up to some box higher up in the diagram.

Now I'd like to have a similar triangle that points *down* to some other box. Unfortunately, there isn't any downward-pointing triangle shape available in Insert > Shapes. And if I try rotating the upward-pointing triangle, the text rotates along with it and ends up being upside down.

[image]

How do I get a triangle like the one on the right, but with the text right side up?

I'm looking to avoid having to make a triangle shape with no text, and a separate text box with text in it, and then overlay them.

Comment: Can you remove text, invert and add text back?

Comment: I can, but how does that help anything?

Comment: The text could be rightside up, since it was added *after* inversion.

Comment: No, it isn't...

Comment: Perhaps make the Text it's own object and then layer it on top of the triangle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Word, I do the following steps:

1. draw a square or rectangular text box
2. change the shape to a downward triangle (see addl. picture)
3. add the text and insert color if required.

   [image]

[image]

Comment: ...why not just start with a downward triangle?